# Function is not changing outer variable

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript

The function is not changing the outer variable

```
function edit(array, letter){
    array = 0;
    letter = 'b';
}
let string = 'a';
let array = [1,0,2];
edit(array, string);
console.log(array, string);// Result [1,0,2] not 0 b
```

Comment: Please post properly what you want to do

Comment: from where variable ```text``` came from?

Comment: Yes, this is how parameters work in JavaScript and many other languages.

Comment: See the top explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language, If you were to pass an object and change the internals of the object you would be able to change the params in this way. But when you try strings or array to primitive you end up with pass by value and the outside variable isn't changed.

Comment: You try it:

let string = 'a';
let array = [1,0,2];
function edit(newArray, letter){
    array = newArray;
    string = letter;
}
edit(array, string);
console.log(0, 'b');